# How to enable Healthkit in watch only app

Tags: swift, healthkit, watchos-6

Does anyone know how to enable Healthkit for an independent watchos only app ? 
When i go to the projects target i can't find capabilities to add to the app.

Am i missing something ?

I tried looking for it in the project but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation i found following information:

In the Project navigator, select the project and in the project editor, select the target.

Choose the target from the Project/Targets pop-up menu or in the Targets section of the outline view if it appears.

In the project editor, click Signing & Capabilities.

Click All or select a specific build configuration.

For example, select Debug if you want to test a capability without adding it to a release build.

Click the + Capability button (Editor > Add Capability) to open the Capability library, .

*The Capability library shows only the capabilities available to the target type and your program membership. If you are not a member of the Apple Developer Program, the capabilities you can add are limited*.

I think it has to do something with the last line. I have no paid membership, and in a later project got the message that not more then 10 app'id's are allowed and i have to wait 7 days. So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project and under targets select `project-name WatchKit Extension`. Then under Signing and Capabilities you can tap the `+` icon on the top left and add HealthKit.

I recommend this series. One of the projects covers getting workouts setup for Apple Watch:

https://www.udemy.com/share/101CJkAkIbcldWQw